# airflow concurrency per dag run

Tags: airflow

I am trying to implement airflow and per dag run I need to run few tasks concurrently. The problem is I am able to find tasks per dag that can be run concurrently but not per dag run.

```
t1 >> t2 >> [t3, t4, t5, t6] >> t7
```

e.g. I have this dag and I run this dag three times in parallel.

Now I want is every dag run should have it's own concurrent task execution limit, not per dag limit.

Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of this tree configuration at airflow.cfg would be helpfull to your issue:
Try parallelism, max_active_tasks_per_dag, max_active_runs_per_dag

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html?highlight=parallelism#parallelism
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html?highlight=parallelism#max-active-tasks-per-dag
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html?highlight=parallelism#max-active-runs-per-dag

If not works, try to read this detailed conf post aboutr concurrency.
https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-scaling-workers/